# Select block of XML with different starting and ending tag using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following:

```
<SomeStuff stuffAttribute1="1" stuffAttribute="2">
    <SomeOtherStuff someOtherStuffAttribute="1" someOtherStuffAttribute="2">
        <SomeWeirdStuff someweirdStuffAttribute="1" someWeirdStuffAttribute="2">
        </SomeWeirdStuff>
    </SomeOtherStuff>
</SomeStuff>
```

How can I use an Xpath to select the XML block as follows:

```
<SomeStuff stuffAttribute1="1" stuffAttribute="2">
<SomeOtherStuff someOtherStuffAttribute="1" someOtherStuffAttribute="2">
    <SomeWeirdStuff someweirdStuffAttribute="1" someWeirdStuffAttribute="2">
    </SomeWeirdStuff>
```

In other words, exclude the closing tag?

Comment: that's not how xml works and that's not how xpath works.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Please tell us what you are _actually_ trying to accomplish rather than your misguided proposal for solving it.

Comment: I need to grab a block of XML that comes back from an API response and store it in a String. I want to truncate the response so I have a block of XML which I can then use to build a further request. So, using XPath, Regex, whatever, I need to be able to say: give me the XML block which starts with this tag <SomeStuff> and ends with </SomeWeirdStuff>

Comment: @Steerpike Ok, you're approaching this problem all wrong. You shouldn't be trying to take an incomplete piece of the XML (presumably as a string) and use it to build another XML document (presumably using string manipulation). You should take the XML you got, load it into a DOM, and then either (a)modify that DOM to the structure that you need by deleting and adding nodes, or (b)create a new DOM, incorporating whatever data you received from the XML you got. I suggest creating a new question where you detail the specifics of what you are actually trying to do (and indicate you are using Java).

Comment: @JLRishe thanks - what you say makes sense and I'm actually doing all the stuff you mention, only I am rushing and overworked and have fired in a badly worded question in haste - but I thank you for your advice which all makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. In xpath, you either select a content, or a block.

Your best bet would be to get the whole block and then run a simple regex on it to remove the end or select only the begining...

Comment: thanks, any clues as to what the regex might look like?

Comment: In your precise example, it would look like that : <SomeStuff[\S\s]+>[\S\s]+(?=</SomeOtherStuff>) in Python. Tested here : https://regex101.com/ . However, it depends on the exact structure. The expression between parenthesis is called a "lookahead", make a quick search about it if you want to understand. You may or may not need to use regexp groups too, depending on your data structure. Tell me if this works for you !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first your XML is not valid. I made you a code sample that you can play with. It will always remove the closing tag of the top most parent. So this is the code snippet:

```
$sample = 
    "<SomeStuff stuffAttribute1=\"1\" stuffAttribute=\"2\">
        <SomeOtherStuff someOtherStuffAttribute=\"2\">
            <SomeWeirdStuff someWeirdStuffAttribute=\"2\">
            </SomeWeirdStuff>
        </SomeOtherStuff>
    </SomeStuff>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($sample);
$firstDocumentElement = $dom->childNodes->item(0);
$closingTag = '</' . $firstDocumentElement->tagName . '>';

header("Content-type: text/plain");
$content = $dom->saveXML();

echo str_replace($closingTag, '', $content);
exit;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SomeStuff stuffAttribute1="1" stuffAttribute="2">
       <SomeOtherStuff someOtherStuffAttribute="2">
            <SomeWeirdStuff someWeirdStuffAttribute="2">
            </SomeWeirdStuff>
       </SomeOtherStuff>
```

Cheers!

Comment: But this will be just a sting, not a valid XML and you cannot create DOMDocument object from it ...

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to tag the question with 'java' but I think I get the idea from your solution - I will give it a try - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem of understanding here. When you use XPath you use it on DOM nodes. Those DOM nodes have been created by a XML parser which read and interpreted your xml.

DOM nodes reside in computer memory and they have no XML text. You could imagine what XPath works on like this (pseudo code):

```
Node(name = "SomeStuff", attributes = {"stuffAttribute1": "1", "stuffAttribute" :"2"} childNodes = [
    Node(name = "SomeOtherStuff" attributes = {"someOtherStuffAttribute": "1", "someOtherStuffAttribute": "2"}, childNodes = [
        Node(name = "SomeWeirdStuff", attributes = {"someweirdStuffAttribute": "1", "someWeirdStuffAttribute": "2"}
    ])
])
```

I hope you get the point.

If you print out what you have in memory now, using an XML serializer, you will get printed out the the whole xml stuff including closing tags.

If you use a json serializer, you will get no closing tags but closing "}", because that is how json works.

If you do not want the closing tags, you can either remove them after printing or you can print the whole thing yourself, and just leave out the closing tags.